# REST API v1 Share Limitations

Tags: linkedin-api

Trying to delete a share that I created using the LinkedIn API. There doesn't seem to be a way of deleting or even amending the visability of a share after it has been posted.
Is the only way of editing a share after it is posted, manually logging into the LinkedIn page in question and deleting the share from the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct.  There is currently no way, via the API, to edit or remove shared content.  It can only be achieved manually via the website at this time.

Comment: Any plans to add this in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

you can delete you shared post via DELETE [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/{encoded](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/%7Bencoded) ugcPostUrn|shareUrn}. For edit u can only edit a text only post. via POST [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{shareURN}](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/%7BshareURN%7D)